# Is it possible to redesign a magnetron to be a receiving device?

Tags: current, electromagnetism, magnetics

**Magnetron- As a [transmitter](http://educypedia.karadimov.info/library/e5500_sm_guide_photo.gif)**

A magentron is used to produce microwaves, by oscillating a magnetic field, and an electric field at a specific frequency.
**Magnetron- As a receiver**

Is it possible to redesign a magnetron to be a receiver of microwaves waves?  By not necessarily splitting the photon into its components, an electric field, and magnetic field?

Comment: NO. The cathode is biased at about -1,200vdc. The Magnetron is an oscillator with a waveguide output. It cannot receive signals. It would be like asking a jet engine to work in reverse.

Comment: I'm not going to bother giving a full explanation, but if you search around some people use some diodes in a waveguide to detect microwave RF energy. Two correctly arranged diodes as detectors give you in-phase quadrature, which can then be processed with normal signal processing techniques.